# Delete is not working in jqx-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, grid

```
function deleteRender(row, column, value) {
      if (!value) {
          return;
      }
      var status = getUserStatus(value);
      var actionText = deleteBlockHtml;
      if (!isUserContext()) {
          actionText = '<span>Delete</span>';
      }
      if (status) {
          actionText = '<span>Activate<span>';
      }
      return '<span class="grid-link-render"><a class="delete-grid-row" href="#" id="deleteUser_' + value.trim() + '">' + actionText + '</a></span>';
  }

 columnList = [
                    {text: 'Status', datafield: 'status', width: "8%", groupable: true, editable: false},
                    {text: 'Action', datafield: '_id', cellsrenderer: deleteRender, width: "10%", groupable: true, editable: false, filterable: false, sortable: false, menu: false},
                ];
```

[image]

I am calling the deleteRender() function on click of my delete button which is present in action.Unfortunately,when i scroll down to bottom it is not getting called in grid.

Can anyone plese help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please share some more code. The method in cellsrenderer method takes care of tailoring the html to be rendered into that cell of that column using the bounded data for that column which is called for each row when the grid is being painted.

i don't think deleteRender should contain the column list in there. Also, can you please show where you are defining the delete event that is attached for that 'Delete' link in the action column ?

Or please let me know if i'm missing something.

Comment: thanks for the code. but i still dont see the event which is called when you click on delete. per your question, im not sure what you mean by - 'which is present in action'. you could use jQuery .on() to bind the click event to the link though. deleteRender is only used for rendering the data as you want to display it. you would still have to attach/bind the events which would actually do the delete. does that make any sense?

Comment: cellsrenderer: deleteRender which is called when button is clicked.

Comment: I think you need to implement a cellclick event and handle it.